# Popup div in flex box

Tags: html, css, popup, flexbox, popupwindow

I've been creating a website thats organized mostly with display:flex. All the content is in one html and using JQ to show() and hide() the different content.  Now I'm trying to create a "pop up" window using a div.  I initially hide() the popup div. when I click the button(which is a flex item) nothing seems to happen.  Its as if the properties of flex are pushing it out of the way. Here is a sample of why my code looks like.  Does anybody have experience with this?

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button-to-click"></div>
  <div class="popUp"></div>
</div>

$(".popUp").hide();
 $(".popUp").click(function () {
        $("#wgl-welcome").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Here is an updated JSFiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish. Of coarse - works in the fiddle haha.  Possible something out side the container is effecting it. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ab3d/97bcnvnr/5/#&togetherjs=5lME62V5tt

Comment: add a minimal verifiable example showing the problem...

Comment: Its updated! thanks! however it work in the fiddle for some reason :/